# Separation of variables on a second order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am attempting to grasp the basics of separation of variables for a second order separable differential equation, and am failing to do so:

Given the equation:

$$ x=\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$$

I know from calculus class intuitively that the solution is:

$$ y=\frac{x^3}{6}$$

But if I am to use separation of variables, why don't I get:

$$ \frac{y^2}{2}=\frac{x^3}{6} $$

Since I should have had to integrate the $y$ side twice as well.

Answer (score 8):

You don't have something like $f(x)dx dx=g(y)dy dy$. You have $f(x) dx =g(y)d\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)$. Remember that the second deriviative is $\frac{d \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)}{dx}$. The actual solution is $\frac{x^3}6+cx+k$, where $c$ and $k$ are constants. This should be your process:

$x=\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$

$x dx=d\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)$

$\int xdx=\int d\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)$

$\frac{x^2}2=\frac{dy}{dx}$

Answer (score 1):

This comes from bad standard notation of the second derivative.  If you want to do algebraic manipulations, the second derivative of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} - \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{d^2x}{dx^2}$.  This is found by using the quotient rule on the first derivative.

However, we can simplify things by not using *either* notation, and simply writing the second derivative as being the differential of the first derivative divided by $dx$:

$$y'' = \frac{d\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)}{dx}$$

This is a form that (a) shows where the differentiation occurs, (b) is algebraically manipulable, and (c) isn't as messy.

So, on your problem, you start out with

$$ x = \frac{d\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)}{dx} $$

Multiplying both side by $dx$ gives you:

$$ x\,dx = d\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)$$

We can integrate that:

$$ \int x\,dx = \int d\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right) \\
\frac{x^2}{2} + C_1 = \frac{dy}{dx}$$
Note that on the right hand side, this works because the integral and differential are opposites, so they basically cancel out (obviously leaving a $+C$ if the integral is the last operation).

Now, we multiply both sides by $dx$ again.  This yields:

$$\frac{x^2}{2}\,dx + C_1\,dx = dy$$

Integrating yields:

$$\int \left(\frac{x^2}{2}\,dx  + C_1\,dx\right) = \int dy \\
\int \frac{x^2}{2}\,dx + \int C_1\, dx = \int dy \\
\frac{x^3}{6} + C_1x + C_2= y $$

That is the mechanics of how it works.

Answer (score -2):

You have treated $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ as $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = (\frac{dy}{dx})^2 = \frac{dydy}{dxdx}$. This of course isn't true. The second derivative of $y$ wrt $x$ is $\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{dy}{dx})$ which if you want to use the fraction analogy can be thought of as $\frac{dy}{dxdx}$. Now, using separation of variable on the equation you've supplied would yield $$\iint  xdxdx = \int  dy$$

Solving this would produce the correct solution. This isn't a mathematically rigorous explanation, but it works to show the difference between $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ and the first derivative squared.

Comment: Your first sentence is correct.  However, there is no sense I can think of in which $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)$ can be thought of as $\frac{dy}{dx\,dx}$.

Comment: I agree. $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} \neq \lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x^2}$. My bad.