# How would you use the separation of variables to solve something like y'''=y?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I was looking up how to solve higher order (specifically second) differential equations with the separation of variables, and I came across this math stack exchange post: [Separation of variables on a second order ODE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1951213/separation-of-variables-on-a-second-order-ode) with someone asking how to solve $\frac {d^2 y} {dx^2} = x$, and someone gave a solution that $\frac {d^2 y} {dx^2} = \frac {d(\frac {dy} {dx})} {dx}$ so you can do $xdx = d(\frac {dy} {dx})$ then integrate and continue from there, but my problem is if you have something like $\frac {d^3 y} {dx^3} = y$ , you could rearrange it like so to be $\frac {1} {y} d(\frac {d^2 y} {dx^2}) = dx$, but how would you integrate $\frac {1} {y} d(\frac {d^2 y} {dx^2})$? It looks absurd.

Comment: This is an autonomous equation, separation of variables makes little sense. There is no similarity between $y''=x$ and $y'''=y$.

Comment: make the ansatz $$y(x)=e^{\lambda x}$$

Comment: Please clarify the intent -- if you want to solve the ODE specifically by separation of variables, this is an irrelevant technique for your type of ODE. If you want to learn how to solve such ODEs altogether, please rephrase the question.

Comment: Separation of variables only works for 1st order equations...

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

General approach for constant coefficients is to assume a solution of the form $y = e^{ax}$ and plug it into your equation. Then, $y'''=y$ becomes $a^3 = 1$ so the solutions are $1$ (the only real solution) and $e^{2i\pi/3}$ and $e^{4i\pi/3}$.

The general solution will have 3 families, corresponding to each of the solutions...

Comment: The question is about "how to use separation of variables".

Comment: @YvesDaoust you already commented that separation of variables is nonsensical in this context. I think OP just wants to understand how to solve it...

Comment: I am glad that you agree that this hint is irrelevant.

Comment: @YvesDaoust on the other hand, i think it is very relevant, and the OP did not express this properly. I think OP wants to solve the ODE (and from later comments, Dr. Graubner seems to agree). How he solves it is rather secondary, or perhaps he misunderstood something in class.

Comment: @YvesDaoust happy to delete the answer as soon as OP posts any sort of clarification whatsoever